# Display current index of iCarousel in a label which is not a subView in ICarousel

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I am using iCarousel in my application,I need to get the current index of the iCarousel and display that index in a label(subView of self.view) which is not a subView of iCarousel.
I am able to get the current index With

```
int index=iCarousel.currentIndex;
```

How can i update the index in label.text that every time when the carousel is Scrolled.
In which method i have to write the code to update label.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whenever you scroll the following delegate will called, so you can update your label here

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated:(iCarousel *)carousel1
{
  int index=carousel1.currentIndex;
  yourlabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",index];
}
```

Comment: For some reason this method is never called. carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange does get called though.

Answer (score 2):

For using the iCarousel, it is better to study its documentation thoroughly before going into its implementation from [iCarousel Documentation](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

So for the issue you are facing , there are 2 methods provided in the documentation -

```
- (NSInteger)indexOfItemView:(UIView *)view;
```

> The index for a given item view in the carousel. Works for item views
>   and placeholder views, however placeholder view indexes do not match
>   the ones used by the dataSource and may be negative (see
>   indexesForVisibleItems property above for more details). This method
>   only works for visible item views and will return NSNotFound for views
>   that are not currently loaded. For a list of all currently loaded
>   views, use the visibleItemViews property.

```
- (NSInteger)indexOfItemViewOrSubview:(UIView *)view
```

> This method gives you the item index of either the view passed or the
>   view containing the view passed as a parameter. It works by walking up
>   the view hierarchy starting with the view passed until it finds an
>   item view and returns its index within the carousel. If no
>   currently-loaded item view is found, it returns NSNotFound. This
>   method is extremely useful for handling events on controls embedded
>   within an item view. This allows you to bind all your item controls to
>   a single action method on your view controller, and then work out
>   which item the control that triggered the action was related to. You
>   can see an example of this technique in the Controls Demo example
>   project.

Hope this helps !! :)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late, but for others, the following delegate method works for me (with multiple carousels)

```
- (void)carouselCurrentItemIndexDidChange:(iCarousel *)carousel
{
    NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);

    if (carousel == carousel2) {
        NSLog(@"here");
        long (or int) currentIndex = carousel.currentItemIndex;

    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is the only delegate method that gets called for me. carouselCurrentItemIndexUpdated never gets called.